# Why do I get an operand type error here when I use a %?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm making a text based RPG and I've been stuck on this for at least a week
This is the enemy class I created and the function i have right now is to attack.

```
class enemy:
    def __init__(self,name,level,health):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.health = health
    def attack(self):
        print "A %r appears! It wants to fight!" % (self.name)
        player.weapon = (raw_input("What do you attack with? >>").lower())
        while (player.health > 0) or (self.health > 0):
            if (player.inventory.get(player.weapon) > 0):
                player.health = player.health - ( ( randint(0,5) ) +  attack_multiplier(self.level) )
                print "%r strikes! Your health is down to %r" %(self.name, player.health)
                if (player.health > 0) and (self.health > 0):
                    if weapon_probability() == "critical hit":
                        self.health -= (((randint(0,5))) +  (attack_multiplier(weapon_levels.get(player.weapon))) * 2)
                        print_slow( "Critical Hit!")
                    elif weapon_probability() == "hit":
                        self.health -=((((randint(0,5))) +  (attack_multiplier(weapon_levels.get(player.weapon)))))
                        print_slow( "Hit!")
                    elif weapon_probability() == "miss":
                        print_slow( "Miss")
                    print_slow("Enemy health down to %r !") % self.health
                elif player.health <= 0:
                    print_slow("Your health...it's falling")
                    break
                elif self.health <= 0:
                    print_slow( "Enemy vanquished!")
                    break
            else:
                print "You don't have that!"
                player.weapon = (raw_input("What do you attack with? >>").lower())
```

This is the error:

```
  File "Central Program.py", line 103, in attack

print_slow("Enemy health down to %d !") % self.health
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Thanks for the help, I've been stuck on this so long and its getting really annoying. I feel like the solution's going to be simple but I dont know what to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply the `%` operator to the *string*, not the return value of `print_slow()`. That function returns `None`, and `None % self.health` raises your error.

Change

```
print_slow("Enemy health down to %d !") % self.health
```

to

```
print_slow("Enemy health down to %d !" % self.health)
```

Note the placement of that closing `)` parenthesis. Your code was applying `%` to the wrong object.

Answer (score 0):

Put `% self.health` inside the parantheses